# Greeks of a Vanilla Option in pyql

Tags: python, quantlib

I'm not sure if I am missing an import, but I do not see a way to get any of the greeks of an option in `pyql`:

```
from quantlib.instruments.api import AmericanExercise, VanillaOption, Put, Call
from quantlib.instruments.payoffs import PlainVanillaPayoff

from quantlib.pricingengines.api import BaroneAdesiWhaleyApproximationEngine
from quantlib.pricingengines.api import FDAmericanEngine
from quantlib.processes.black_scholes_process import BlackScholesMertonProcess
from quantlib.quotes import SimpleQuote
from quantlib.settings import Settings
from quantlib.time.api import Actual365Fixed, Date, May, Mar, TARGET
from quantlib.termstructures.volatility.equityfx.black_vol_term_structure \
    import BlackConstantVol
from quantlib.termstructures.yields.api import FlatForward

option = VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)
```

How do I get the delta of this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the greeks are only provided in some cases. I am not sure why the built in engines don't just provide the greeks as explained in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgUlBB59Ll0

Comment: That's because the numerical calculation is costly (it needs two additional price evaluations per greek), so it has to be requested explicitly.

Comment: Agreed. But as a library implementer, why not implement the methods, and  as a user, pass a bool that indicates if you want the greeks computed or not? Or alternatively, add functions that separate greek computation from their optimized versions.

Comment: Long story, and probably starting to get off-topic. I'll try to write it up on my blog and post a link. The TL;DR version: the engine (or the instrument) is not supposed to modify its inputs, since they might be shared by other instruments. It could clone them, but that a lot more complex than leaving it to the user to perturb the market and recalculate all affected instruments.